# DNS on a website

Tags: dns, websites

I have a Joomla website and I wanna give it a domain name.

Should I install DNS server (BIND9) on my Ubuntu
or should I buy a domain name from the internet?

if should I buy a domain name, is there any domain name for free for like a few days to test my website?

My website I currently testing out on Joomla on Ubuntu LTS 16.0.4

Comment: It all depends on who you want to be able to resolve the domain name. If it's just you (and your LAN), `dnsmasq` publishes what is in `/etc/hosts`. If you want the World to resolve the address, you need to but a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to buy a domain and *possibly* set up a DNS server yourself.

Many registrars, however, provide DNS hosting for your domain, so that you don't have to go through the headache of rolling out a DNS server yourself.  Namecheap, Gandi, GoDaddy, they all provide hosted DNS.  You could also buy the domain and roll out Cloudflare DNS, as an option, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You buy a domain at a domain registrar.  There are plenty to choose from for the generic top levels, such as .com and .net.  Choose one that's cheap but has a good reputation.

Then, you need DNS hosting.  Many web hosts can provide this.  Nowadays many domain registrars can too.  Or you can use a third party like Cloudflare, which can do it free.  You just need to decide.

You don't need to, and probably shouldn't, set up a DNS server like Bind yourself.  Setting up a DNS server is something best left to the experts.